# Finding Pickel File in local files

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, decision-tree

```
import pickle
filename='pred_model1'
pickle.dump(b_dtc, open(filename,'wb'))
#here b_dtc is my modelname`
```

when I executed the code it works well but how to know where the pickle file is downloaded in my system, as it is not present in my current working directory.
note: i am using collab

Answer (score 0):

If you did not save the file in your drive after a while it will be removed from colab so it is better to override you drive and save it in your drive by specifying your directory in your drive using dump

```
import os
import pickle

filename = 'pred_model1'
path = '/path/to/save/pickle/'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(b_dtc, file)
```